# Google Analytics Management API- How to add users to a profile

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way for me to allow my clients to add themselves to a specified google analytics profile throught the google analytics management API?

I'm basically trying to get away from having to sign into google analytics to add each individual client to their profile. I would like to create a way for them to add themselves to their profile as a user through an admin area.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, no way.  It's done in this manner to protect your information.

Comment: I have one, its still say insufficient permissions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the API. Check out the api explorer.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/

[image]

Comment: I did this but it gave me errors:
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission"}],"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission"}}
Note: I already have my mangement permission granted